# Get a list of results from ExecutorService.invokeAll

Tags: java, guava

I'm probably missing something in the Guava API. How can I use ExecutorService.invokeAll with Futures.allAsList without casting?

My usecase is that I would like to submit a List of Callables and wait until all are executed (in parallel). I'm only interested in the list of results from the Callables.

```
    ListeningExecutorService executor = MoreExecutors.sameThreadExecutor(); //or any other ExecutorService
    List<Future<Object>> futures = 
        executor.invokeAll(singletonList(new Callable<Object>() {
            @Override public Object call() throws Exception {
                return 42;
            }
        }
    ));
    Iterable<ListenableFuture<Object>> listableFutures = 
        (Iterable<ListenableFuture<Object>>) (Iterable) futures;
    //would like to use "futures" here
    ListenableFuture<List<Object>> r = Futures.allAsList(listableFutures);
    System.out.println(r.get());
```

In a perfect world I would like to call `ListeningExecutorService.allAsList(Collection<? extends Callable<T>> tasks)` and get a `Future<List<T>>` or even `List<T>`.

Comment: Out of interest, why do you need listenable futures at all? All the tasks will have completed before `invokeAll` returns anyway, so what would you be listening for?

Comment: Don't care about ListenableFuture, but Futures.allAsList is defined as allAsList(Iterable<? extends ListenableFuture<? extends V>> futures).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope.  You're supposed to do the cast.  It can't be avoided, due to the way Java restricts overriding of methods.

The Javadoc for `ListeningExecutorService.invokeAll` states

> All elements in the returned list must be ListenableFuture instances.

Comment: I'll use a for loop to populate a list then. Wrapping the executor and casting is too much overhead for such a tiny functionality (I do not need a Future<List>)

Comment: Meh.  The cast will be _safe_, so I'd still do the cast in your shoes -- it's cheaper than a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

As it's not supported to use Futures.allAsList without a cast to `Iterable<? extends ListenableFuture<? extends V>>` the simple solution to use a for loop should be the best:

```
    ListeningExecutorService executor = MoreExecutors.sameThreadExecutor();
    List<Future<Object>> futures = executor.invokeAll(
        singletonList(new Callable<Object>() {
            @Override public Object call() throws Exception {
                return 42;
           }
        }
    ));
    List<Object> r = Lists.newArrayList();
    for (Future<Object> future : futures) r.add(future.get());
```